# my insert query is working in my localhost but not in web server

Tags: php, database, insert

I am using flex builder 3 to insert into mysql database using php and everything is working perfectly in my localhost, the problem is when I deploy the project in the web server and run it, it connect to the database but i can't insert data ( it shows nothing when i insert data )
another stupid thing is in another piece of code for retrieving (select) data that works good on both my localhost and web server.

here is the php code:

```
<?php 

$host = "******"; 
$user = "******"; 
$pass = "******"; 
$database = "******"; 

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 

$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$steam = $_POST['steam'];
$c1 = $_POST['c1'];
$c2 = $_POST['c2'];
$c3 = $_POST['c3'];

$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `phantom`.`members` (`TF2_Nickname` ,`Steam_User_Name`,
`class1` ,`class2` ,`class3` ,`time`) VALUES ($nickname,  $steam,  $c1,  $c2,  $c3,NOW())");

?>
```

Comment: Check your MySQL version on the server.

Comment: Also, check if the tables exist and so on. The question is pretty unclear now.

Comment: Double-check information to login in mysql, and check if the database exists on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [declare the values as strings in your MySQL query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html) as well:

```
"INSERT INTO `phantom`.`members` (`TF2_Nickname`, `Steam_User_Name`, `class1`, `class2`, `class3`, `time`)
 VALUES ('$nickname', '$steam', '$c1', '$c2', '$c3', NOW())"
```

And you should also prepare them in some way to avoid that they are mistakenly treated as SQL command (see [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). PHP has the [`mysql_real_escape_string` function](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to do that:

```
"INSERT INTO `phantom`.`members` (`TF2_Nickname`, `Steam_User_Name`, `class1`, `class2`, `class3`, `time`)
 VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($nickname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($steam)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($c1)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($c2)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($c3)."', NOW())"
```

Comment: still the same but thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Insert into requires either user right or admin right. Check if by chance You didnt modify somewhere in the code these rights, e.g., You changed by hand the name of your admin... If it works the select it is because selecting doesnt need so many rights. Even non user status can retrieve info through select but insert needs special rights. You know your code so think about this difference